# Infolog with large amount of messages

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I am having an issue using Dynamics Ax 2012 Enterprise Portal where I am displaying every validation error in the infolog to a custom page in a modal dialog. If there are many errors, the infolog will place itself above the page, and I have to click and drag text to force the window to scroll up and see the errors. What can I do about big infologs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out how to add a scroll bar to the infolog.

The div containing the infolog has the class dynInfologOuter. If you edit the AXEP.css file to add:

```
max-height: 120px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

... to the .dynInfologOuter css class, the infolog will add the scrollbar and display all the error messages in that height, and the 110px allows for 5 errors to show up.

This, however, will change the infologs *everywhere* in Enterprise Portal, which isn't necessarily a bad thing to have them all like this.